# Qt translations with arguments

Tags: c++, qt, translation, qt-linguist

I've run into a problem using Qt to dynamically translate an application. 
All strings shown in the UI are wrapped in tr() calls, so I can see them in the QtLinguist.

My problem now is this: Let's say I have a string with a placeholder %1: 
`tr("Foo %1");`

I understand that I can fill the placeholder like this

`tr("Foo %1").arg(myPlaceholder);` or `tr("Foo %1").arg(tr(myPlaceholder));`

but there are no seperate calls to the possible values of myPlaceholder, so they don't show up in QtLinguist.

What would be the best way to add the possible placeholder values to my translation files? I've read in another thread that it would be wrong to manually edit the *.ts files.

Comment: You should be using `tr` when you assign a string literal to `myPlaceholder`, not inside `arg` as you've done above.

Comment: @RA. ....yes, that would make a lot more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `tr()` must be a string literal. The value of the tr-expression is a `QString` - that's why you can use its `arg` method etc.